# javascript mixin access to objects this

Tags: javascript, node.js, mixins

I've created an object and a mixin, i've assigned the mixin to the Object, but I don't have access to the object from the mixin , it seems?

mixin.js

```
module.exports = {
  doSomething: () => {
    let something = this.something.title;
  }
};
```

object.js

```
class Thing {   
  constructor(something) {
    this.something = something;   
  }

  _otherFunction() {
    // does stuff
  } 
}

module.exports = Thing;
```

index.js

```
const Something = require('./mixin');
const Thing = require('./Object');

Object.assign(Thing.prototype, Something);
```

when I then instantiate Thing and call `doSomething()`, it then can't get access to this.something... so

```
let thing = new Thing({title: 'abc'});
thing.doSomething();
```

i get the error Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ditch the arrow function, in favour of a vanilla function, because the arrow function loses the scope of `this`.

```js
class Thing {   
  constructor(something) {
    this.something = something;   
  }
}

const mixin = {
  // changed arrow function to regular function
  doSomething: function () {
    console.log(this.something.title)
  }
}

const thing = new Thing({title: 'abc'})
Object.assign(thing, mixin)
thing.doSomething()
```

From [MDN: Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression... and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.

A lot of people mistakenly believe that the sole feature of an arrow function is shorter syntax - it's not. It's primary practical feature is that it doesn't create it's own `this`.

Comment: Just goes to show that you can't just jump on the shiny new features without understanding them first.